# open a form or KryptonForm in KryptonDockableWorkspace

Tags: krypton-toolkit

Is there any way to open a form or KryptonForm in KryptonDockableWorkspace?

I want to open my form or KryptonForm as a Dockable Content in KryptonDockableWorkspace.

I have tried to add my form as a control in KryptonPage but it is not possible as form is a top level control and cannot be added as a control, and I don't want to re create all my forms as user controls as I have already developed my application.

Please help me in this.
Thanks